# Android API call using RxJava, response is null

Tags: android, rx-java, job-scheduling, evernote

This is my function for sending a report model to back end, get a response back and save it. The problem is that the response is always null.

```
public static Observable<Report> createReport(CreateReportRequestModel model) {
    return getApiService().createReport(model)
            .map(response -> {
                setReport(response);
                return response;
            });
```

The Report POJO class has all the fields from the response and if I send the same data from postman it's working as intended (so the problem is not in the API).

Here is the subscriber that gives back SUCCESS, and if it goes to onNext the model part is null, but the result is still SUCCESS.

```
CreateReportRequestModel model = gson().fromJson(json, CreateReportRequestModel.class);
    Observable<Report> report = createReport(model);
    report.subscribe(new Subscriber<Report>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            resultHolder.setResult(Result.SUCCESS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.d(e, "Upload Error");
                resultHolder.setResult(Result.RESCHEDULE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Report model) {
            Timber.d("On Next " + model);
        }
    });
    return resultHolder.result();
}
```

All in all, I don't know why the response is always null.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you added the relevant converter factories to Retrofit? You'll need RxJava and Gson (I'm assuming you're using Retrofit)

Comment: post the Report pojo class

Comment: @JoshLaird Yes. Here it is `Retrofit.Builder retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson()))`